# Create a "listener" to slider in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am creating a GUI in which I display a 3D image and navigate through it using a slider. I want to draw some points (using a "WindowButtonDownFcn" callback, i.e., I do not have any information about the position of the slider once I call the drawing function) over a certain slice using the mouse and that point should appear over all other slices and be editable as soon as the user uses the slider to switch between slices.

One possible solution that came to my mind is use "listeners", so whenever the user moves the slider, my drawing function is notified and the slider position is passed to it.
.
Following the MATLAB tutorial, I defined my classes so I can include the listener to my code, but it is not working.
.
How can I implement this functionality?

Code for GUI:

```
function varargout = teste_window(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @teste_window_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @teste_window_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


function teste_window_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

load IMG.mat
nimgs = 10;
imgs = zeros(size(img, 1), size(img, 2), nimgs);
for ii = 1: nimgs
    imgs(:, :, ii) = img;
end

imshow(imgs(:, :, 1), [], 'Parent', handles.axs_plot);
handles.imgs   = imgs;
handles.nimgs  = nimgs;
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes teste_window wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = teste_window_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in btn_ok.
function btn_ok_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

btns = findobj(hObject, 'Style', 'pushbutton');
set(btns, 'Enable', 'Off');
[x, y] = getRoi4(handles.axs_plot)
handles.xcoord = x;
handles.ycoord = y;
set(btns, 'Enable', 'On');
guidata(hObject, handles);
% dragDrop(handles.axs_plot);


% --- Executes on slider movement.
function sld_img_pos_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
nimgs = handles.nimgs;
set(handles.sld_img_pos, 'Max', nimgs);
set(handles.sld_img_pos, 'SliderStep', [1/nimgs , 1/nimgs]);
sld_val = round(get(handles.sld_img_pos, 'Value'));
if (sld_val < 1)
    sld_val = 1;
elseif (sld_val > nimgs)
    sld_val = nimgs;
end
imshow(handles.imgs(:, :, sld_val), [], 'Parent', handles.axs_plot);


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function sld_img_pos_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end
```

Code for getRoi4:

```
    function [x, y, xc, yc] = getRoi4(axeshandle)

zoom off;
x  = [];
y  = [];
xc = [];
yc = [];
th   = linspace(0., 2.*pi, 40);
fig = ancestor(axeshandle, 'figure');
xlim = get(axeshandle, 'XLim');
ylim = get(axeshandle, 'YLim');
set(axeshandle, 'XLim', xlim, 'YLim' , ylim, 'NextPlot', 'add');
set(fig, 'KeyPressFcn', @keyRead, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', @mouseRead);

uiwait(fig);

    function keyRead(src, callback)
        key = callback.Key;
        returnPressed = strcmp(key, 'return');
        %         deletePressed = strcmp(key, 'backspace');
        if returnPressed
            set(fig, 'KeyPressFcn', '');
            set(fig, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', '');
            uiresume(fig);
        end
    end

    function mouseRead(src, callback)
        mouseKey = get(fig, 'SelectionType');
        leftMouse   = strcmp(mouseKey, 'normal');
        rigthMouse  = strcmp(mouseKey, 'alt');
        middleMouse = strcmp(mouseKey, 'extend');
        % LEFT CLICK:
        if leftMouse
            cp = get(axeshandle, 'CurrentPoint');
            x = [x, cp(1, 1)];
            y = [y, cp(1, 2)];
            plot(axeshandle,  x,  y, '*b');
            hold on;
            [xc, yc] = getCirc(x, y, xc, yc);
            npts = size(xc, 1);
            for ii = 1: npts
                plot(axeshandle, xc(ii, :), yc(ii, :), 'c')
            end

            % RIGHT CLICK
        elseif rigthMouse
            lc      = get(axeshandle, 'CurrentPoint');
            dist    = sqrt((lc(1, 1) - xc).^2. + (lc(1, 2) - yc).^2);
            [ix, ~] = find(min(min(dist)) == abs(dist));
            ix      = ix(1);
            set(fig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @(xc, yc, index)dragPoint, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', @(s,e)stopDrag);

            % MIDDLE CLICK
        elseif middleMouse
            cp = get(axeshandle, 'CurrentPoint');
            if ~isempty(x)
                [~, ind] = min((x - cp(1,1)).^2 + (y - cp(1,2)).^2);
                ind    = ind(1);
                x(ind) = [];
                y(ind) = [];
                xc(ind, :) = [];
                yc(ind, :) = [];
                dots = findobj(get(axeshandle, 'Children'), 'Type', 'Line');
                set(dots, 'XData', x, 'YData', y, 'color', 'blue', 'Marker', '*', 'LineStyle', 'None');
                npts = size(xc, 1);
                for ii = 1: npts
                    plot(axeshandle, xc(ii, :), yc(ii, :), 'c')
                end
            end
        end

        % DRAG AND DROP:
        function dragPoint(src, callback)
            xcenter = x(ix);
            ycenter = y(ix);
            cp      = get(axeshandle, 'CurrentPoint');
            radius  = sqrt((cp(1, 1) - xcenter)^2. + (cp(1, 2) - ycenter)^2.);
            newxc   = radius*cos(th) + xcenter;
            newyc   = radius*sin(th) + ycenter;
            dots = findobj(get(axeshandle, 'Children'), 'Type', 'Line');
            set(dots, 'XData', x, 'YData', y, 'color', 'blue', 'Marker', '*', 'LineStyle', 'None');
            xc(ix, :) = newxc;
            yc(ix, :) = newyc;
            npts = size(xc, 1);
            for jj = 1: npts
                plot(axeshandle, xc(jj, :), yc(jj, :), 'c')
            end
        end

        function stopDrag(src, callback)
            set(fig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', '');
            set(fig, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', '');
        end

    end

    function [xc, yc] = getCirc(x, y, xc, yc)

        r    = 10;
        npts = length(x);
        xc(npts, :) = r*cos(th) + x(npts);
        yc(npts, :) = r*sin(th) + y(npts);

    end

end
```

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: I don't understand why you don't have access to the position of your slider while in your callback. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just posted the code for the GUI and the code for the callback.